# How can I customize message box in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, messagebox

I want to be able to customise messagebox button from the classical YesNo, okonly and the rest of them

Instead of msgbox("hello world", vbOKonly). i have tried to use another word like vbContinue but i got an error.

Comment: You could create a form to mimic the message box.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an easy task, but it can be done as shown in my article:

[Modern/Metro style message box and input box for Microsoft Access 2013+](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17684/Modern-Metro-style-message-box-and-input-box-for-Microsoft-Access-2013.html)

(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article.)

Code is way too much to post here, but it can found on **GitHub** as well: [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox)